# Wordpress Spider Catalog Images only thumbnails links are being referenced

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a series of images that the Spider Catalog plugin is using. However when it requests these photo's only the thumbnail versions show. But I want the original images to show. I want to change  . $attach_url . so that it only calls for the links of the images as opposed to the links to the images with thumbnails sizes.

```
$small_images_str = '';
$small_images_count = 1;
$imgurl = explode(";;;", $row->image_url);
foreach ($imgurl as $img) {

if ($img !== '******0') {

  $image_with_atach_id = explode('******', $img);
    if (isset($image_with_atach_id[1]) && $image_with_atach_id[1]) {
      $array_with_sizes = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_with_atach_id[1]);
      $attach_url = $array_with_sizes[0];
    } else {
      $attach_url = $image_with_atach_id[0];
      }
    $img = $imgurl[1];
    $small_images_str .= '<img style="width: 100%" src="' . $attach_url . '" />';
    $small_images_count++;
    }
  }
  if ($small_images_count > 1)
    echo $small_images_str;
  else
    echo '&nbsp;';
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing $attach_url to $image worked for me!

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was wrong and why did this help?